# Facebook analytics for apps get gender and age

Tags: facebook-analytics

I just started using Facebook Analytics for Apps and everything is looking great, I'm logging events etc, but still not getting age and gender data, no matter if the user logs or not. I've searched the documentation for some rule or best practice, but no solution so far.

Let me know if I'm missing something. Platform is Unity using the Facebook SDK for Unity.

Comment: Can you provide some more detail? You'll only see demographics if you're looking at over 100 users - if you had less than that over the last 28 days or your segment is filtering to less than 100 people - the data will be redacted. Can you share which specific demographics you can't see and the error message you're seeing.

Answer (score 4):

Facebook Analytics only shares aggregated and anonymized demographics to protect the privacy of it's users. Therefore you need to be looking at at least 100 unique users before demographic data will be displayed.

Comment: Could you provide the official doc or site?